# Does the '?' operator automatically free the value once it reaches the end of the statement? If so, how can I not drop the value while being borrowed?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to borrow the value of 'main_element' so 'sec_element' can access the value. While borrowed, the value suddenly got dropped. Maybe it's because of the '?' operator? Because I'm checking if a web element is present or not. Examples are appreciated.

```
use thirtyfour_sync::{error::WebDriverError, Keys::Enter, prelude::*};
fn main() -> Result<(), WebDriverError>{
    let browser = DesiredCapabilities::edge();
    let driver = WebDriver::new("http://localhost:4444", &browser)?;
    driver.get("https://www.bing.com")?;

    let main_element = driver.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_c"))?.find_element(By::Id("b_searchBoxForm"))?;

    let sec_element = main_element.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_q"))?.find_element(By::Id("b_searchbox"))?;
    sec_element.send_keys("ksiOlajidebt")?;
    sec_element.send_keys(Enter)?;
        
    Ok(())
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
> error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
>       --> src/main.rs:9:28
>        |
>     9  |         let main_element = driver.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_c"))?.find_element(By::Id("b_searchBoxForm"))?;
>        |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                             
> - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
>        |                            |
>        |                            creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
>     10 |
>     11 |         let sec_element = main_element.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_q"))?.find_element(By::Id("b_searchbox"))?;
>        |                           ---------------------------------------------- borrow later used here
>        |
>        = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
>     
>     error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
>       --> src/main.rs:11:27
>        |
>     11 |         let sec_element = main_element.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_q"))?.find_element(By::Id("b_searchbox"))?;
>        |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       
> - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
>        |                           |
>        |                           creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
>     12 |                 sec_element.send_keys("ksiOlajidebt")?;
>        |                 ------------------------------------- borrow later used here
>        |
>        = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe it's because of the '?' operator?

Not really. The problem is *as the compiler tells you* that you have a temporary (created by `find_element`) which is only *borrowed* by the next call (also `find_element`).

Temporaries are only kept alive until the end of the statement, so as soon as the `;` is hit the temporary will be dropped, and thus the next expression can not work with the borrow.

Comment: @user17250991 Does this answer make sense to you? If so then click the ✓. If not then leave a comment, asking for an explanation.